# Systemd PrivateTmp and JoinsNamespaceOf

Tags: systemd, sandbox

I have two service definitions which look like this:

service_a.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceA

[Service]
JoinsNamespaceOf=service_b.service
PrivateTmp=yes
```

service_b.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceB

[Service]
PrivateTmp=yes
```

service_b writes a file to `/tmp/some_file.bin`, which works. 
The file is written to the PrivateTmp of the Unit. 
After writing it, service_b invokes a DBus Call on service_a,
passing '/tmp/some_file.bin' as one of the parameters. 
When running,
service_a is complaining 'no such file /tmp/some_file.bin',
indicating that resolution of the tmp directory did not work. 
Why does service_a not resolve the /tmp/some_file.bin to the correct private temp of service_b?

Disclaimer: yes, I reloaded the system-daemon and restarted both services.

Comment: Does the b service continue running? Or could its /tmp have been removed before a starts?

Comment: No b_service is running constantly, a_service is of type dbus so will be started once dbus messages are sent.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?):  [systemd PrivateTmp/JoinsNamespaceOf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378250/80216), where [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378250/systemd-privatetmp-joinsnamespaceof#comment672595_378259) suggests that the `JoinsNamespaceOf` setting should be in the `[Unit]` part.